# Can a Database Scale Up?

Tags: relational-database, cloud-computing, azure, aws

Microservices are the latest software development craze. All the kids are doing it. When I started hearing about the concept, the first advantage that came to mind was the single responsibility principle. If you take the principle from other aspects of the software engineering principle, it seems to follow than a service - like a class, or library should only do one thing, and do it well. I'll give Microservices that.

However, performance, and scalability were not things that sprang to mind. Without getting in to a huge discussion, there will probably always be cross-talk amongst services which will mean that not only could performance degrade because servers are weighed down with load, but network latency can and probably will degrade performance.

Then, someone told me that they had broken their service up in to 20+ Microservices for the purpose of scalability. This has perplexed me somewhat. I had to probe them by what they meant. Surely, Cloud computing on Azure and so on had solved this problem? When I probed a little further, I was told that a database can not scale up, so no matter how many computers you have in the cluster, the database will always be the bottleneck. The monolith database must be broken down in to smaller chunks for each service. Excuse me? A database can not scale up? Have Microsoft, Amazon, and Google just been lying about their scaling database platforms?

[Azure Cosmos](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/cosmos-db/)

[Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/)

[Amazon Relational Database Service](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/)

Literally, that's my question. Have Microsoft, Amazon, and Google just been lying about their scaling database platforms? Don't they work? I mean, if these platforms do scale up in the sense that more resources are added with replication and so on, then why would breaking a monolith database up in to smaller chunks make it perform better?

Have you tried out these platforms? Are you running very large databases with lots of tables, rows, columns with thousands of transactions per second? What's the consensus on this? Is there some reason that using these scalable database platforms is not as good as breaking the databases down in to smaller chunks?

For the purpose of this question, assume that sharding can not be used as the primary scaling technique. The database must scale with millions of rows, lots of columns and tables.

*PS: This isn't a question of whether or not Microservices are a good idea. The question is very simple.* **Can a database scale up?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scale horizontally a microservice that holds a database](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/383050/how-to-scale-horizontally-a-microservice-that-holds-a-database)

Comment: ,,, and don't get me wrong, but on this site, questions have a way better chance to survive when written in a focussed manner. The community here usually does not need to know the whole discussion going back and forth in ones head to understand what they are asking.

Comment: It's a simple question. Does database scaling work? It's not about how to scale microservices.

Comment: Exactly my point - the whole discussion about what you think about Microservices in the first half of your question makes it hard to understand what you really want to know. And the top answer to that other question holds already a simple answer: learn about [sharding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture))

Comment: I can delete the background about microservices if that helps. I'm not interested in sharding. My whole question is about whether or not a single , large database can scale up. Obviously, that's going to involve replication etc. and the question was about whether or not people had actually managed to get it working.

Comment: don't worry about the votes, they only affect the long term life of your question as part of the site. its a fine question

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can scale databases.

Also, with a strict interpretation of monolith and microservice there generally shouldnt be *this kind* of performance scaling advantage to microservices. A monolith can be just all the microservices in one big package.

It sounds to me like this person is using the term 'monolith' to imply a solution which is very tied to the database and probably has business logic in sprocs, views, triggers etc

When they say 'microservice' they really mean their new solution which has broken those ties.

Although a db can be scalled, its expensive and harder to do than scalling a well programmed microservice. You can simply deploy more of them on cheap boxes behind a load balancer.

When people run into scalling problems 90% of the time its because of the way they interact with large, centralised databases which have reached the limits they were initially expected to consume.

If you can take chunks of your monolith out of that pattern, move them away from the db and implement them is a way designed to scale. Then "moving to microservices has helped us scale" is true. Even though in theory you could have refactored the entire monolith for the same result.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it more expensive to scale up? I thought the point of these scaling databases were that you only pay for what you use...

Comment: I think you've answered my question more or less. But can you provide any studies or empirical evidence to show that scalable databases are a proven technology? I believe you're right but how can others be convinced?

Comment: these kinds of databases are intrisincally resource intensive. plus they a central point that all the apps use. They need the most cpu power, storage, fail over, etc etc. You can run most microservices on hardware less powerful than a calculator. Any processes that can be taken out of the db means the db has more resource available for returning and storing data

Comment: Why are they intrinsically resource intensive? Because of replication?

Comment: because of the volume of data they have to store

Comment: But you still have to store the same amount of volume no matter what. If you break the database up, it's just spread across more database servers.

Comment: The thing is that  the db in this type of monolith is central to its working. say its a eCommerce site. If the db runs slow customer get page timeouts and cant buy stuff. Its a big deal. Now you have a new feature which say, gives them 10% off on tuesdays. if you change the monolith to add an extra parameter to the query its running that code over potentially millions of rows of data. It runs super fast when you have 100 customers, but crashes when you have 1000000. move that same code out of the db and its not got that problem any more.

Comment: So you're saying it can't scale up?

Comment: Im saying there are ways of doing things which don't scale well. But they dont equate to monolith bad, microservice good

Comment: Of course, but are you saying that there is some point at which a monolith database is just going to be slow no matter what? For example, there's just a point where 1000000 customers is going to push it over the edge? No matter how many resources you throw at it? I don't have experience with databases servers like Cosmos DB and so on, so I have no way of validating their claim that there databases can scale up. My question is whether there will just be a choke point where a monolith database simply will not cope anymore.

Comment: 'monolith' means putting all your code in a single app. it doesnt refer to the db. Databases can handle millions of rows easy. as long as you are just doing simple selects with indexes and not sprocs with business logic in them.

Comment: I'm not talking about the app. I'm just talking about the database. So, really there's no need to break databases up in to smaller chunks, and Cosmos DB etc. will be able to handle huge databases with lots of data. Is that what you're saying? So, when the next person tells me a in meeting that they can't, what do I say? How do I not come across as naive?

Comment: erm, unfortunately you are coming across a bit naive. technically yes a db can scale. But when people talk about 'scalablity' they are balancing costs, time and the risk levels of making the changes needed. If you have a 10 year old legacy application, you don't want to rewrite it all from scratch for any reason. even though techincally you could do so to make it scale better

Comment: also, its the way the app is written rather than the db which is really the problem (unless you get to billions of records)

Comment: Why are the balancing costs higher with a single cosmos db than several SQL server dbs broken up in to smaller chunks? Please forget about the app part. I'm only talking about the db.

Comment: monolith and microservice refer to the application. not the db. Cosmo is a NoSql db and mssql is a relational db. They have different restriction on what they can do. Nosql dbs are 'more scalable' because the design forces you to divide your data up. writing the app in a different way. It's a bit sketchy to make a direct comparisom between the two techs

Comment: What I suggest you do is write a new question explaining what your application does,  current architecture and what scalablity limit it has reached. then ask for a recommended solution to the scaling problem

Comment: I've changed the title of the question. I was asking about relational databases. I assumed cosmos db was a Relational database. So does that mean a Relational database can not scale up?